# Vite complains that material UI icons can not be resolved

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

I migrated my project from CRA to Vite.

When I run `npm run dev` I get this error:

```
The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

  @mui/icons-material/Article (imported by /Blog/Admin/Exports.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Comment (imported by /Social/Admin/Comment/View.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/TextSnippet (imported by /Contents/Admin/Page/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/FindInPage (imported by /Contents/Admin/Page/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/AccountTree (imported by /Taxonomy/Admin/Hierarchy/Manage.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/LocalOffer (imported by /Taxonomy/Admin/Tag/Manage.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/NoteAlt (imported by /Forms/Admin/Form/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/EventNote (imported by /Logs/Admin/Exports.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Navigation (imported by /Navigation/Admin/Exports.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Abc (imported by /Contents/Admin/Exports.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Fingerprint (imported by /Entities/Admin/Exports.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Support (imported by /Ticketing/Admin/Exports.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Shuffle (imported by /Entities/Admin/EntityType/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Delete (imported by /Logs/Admin/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Search (imported by /Contents/Admin/Image/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Done (imported by /Ticketing/Admin/Ticket/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/SyncAlt (imported by /Accounts/Admin/User/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Error (imported by /Logs/Admin/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/ListAlt (imported by /Contents/Admin/Section/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Message (imported by /Ticketing/Admin/Ticket/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Link (imported by /Navigation/Admin/LinkGroup/List.jsx)
  @mui/icons-material/Bolt (imported by /Contents/Admin/Section/List.jsx)

Are they installed?
```

Even when I run `npm install` and then run `npm run dev` I see this message.

I manually went into `node_modules/@mui/icons-material` and `cat Article.js`:

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _createSvgIcon = _interopRequireDefault(require("./utils/createSvgIcon"));

var _jsxRuntime = require("react/jsx-runtime");

var _default = (0, _createSvgIcon.default)( /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsx)("path", {
  d: "M19 3H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-5 14H7v-2h7v2zm3-4H7v-2h10v2zm0-4H7V7h10v2z"
}), 'Article');

exports.default = _default;
```

So It's there. I can't find out why it can not be resolved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The mui icon files have a `.js` extension. In our vite config we were only resolving `.ts` and `.tsx` files. Adding the `.js` extension fixed the error.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what you did to resolve the files?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error about a local file. Same message:

> The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved.

The fix for me was to add "./" before my file name. So "index.js" became "./index.js".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Remove caret symbol(^) from installed MUI packages in package.json.

For example:

```
Before - "@mui/base": "^5.0.0-alpha.60"

After - "@mui/base": "5.0.0-alpha.60"
```